# How can I find the lat/lon of a marker in MapBox?

Tags: javascript, methods, marker, mapbox

Here's my code

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-20v6611k').setView([37.9, -77],4);

var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(37.9, -77), {
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-color': 'CC0033'}),
                draggable: true
            });

marker.bindPopup('This marker is draggable! Move it around.');
marker.addTo(map);

//my code

marker.on('mousedown', function(e){
        location = marker.getLatLng();
        document.getElementById('locationBox').innerHTML = "poop";
});
```

The marker on the map can be dragged anywhere.  I'm trying to take the longitude and latitude of the marker after the marker has been dragged somewhere which is why I'm using the 
    marker.on('mousedown', function(e){
event handler.
I have two problems.  I'm trying to nest another event handler

```
marker.on('mouseup', function(e){
```

inside that so the location is grabbed once the marker is let go from being dragged but the 'mouseup' method doesn't work.

Second problem

```
    location = marker.getLatLng();
```

Doesn't store lat/lon in location but rather just opens a new URL I haven't configured for.

How can I use Javascript or Jquery to grab the location of the marker after it is dragged and then dropped, and how can I appropiately store the lat/lon in a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use the `dragend` event as it fires after a marker has been dragged. If you peer into what `e.target` returns there is a `_latlng` object that gives you the details you need:

```
marker.on('dragend', function(e){
    console.log(e.target._latlng);
});
```

An underscore used in a method name implies that its private so there may be a more appropriate way to access this but for now should suit your needs.

Comment: You should use `.getLatLng()` instead, a public, documented method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
console.log(marker._lngLat.lat);
console.log(marker._lngLat.lng);
```